# Dictionary to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to read an input from excel in python which I convert into a dictionary , like:

```
import xlrd, json

d = {}
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)  
data=[]



for i in range(1,sh.nrows):
    d={}
    for j in range(sh.ncols):
        d[sh.cell(0,j).value] = sh.cell(i,j).value

    data.append(d)    
data
```

The resulting data is of the format

```
[{'Age': 20.0, 'Brothers': 2.0, 'Name': 'Josh', 'Nationality': 'UK'},
 {'Age': 22.0, 'Brothers': 1.0, 'Name': 'Kim', 'Nationality': 'France'}]
```

My "json" file output should look exactly like this

```
{
'Children':[
{'Age': 20.0, 'Brothers': 2.0, 'Name': 'Josh', 'Nationality': 'UK'},
{'Age': 22.0, 'Brothers': 1.0, 'Name': 'Kim', 'Nationality': 'France'}
]
}
```

However, When I call json.dumpts(data) I obtain something like this

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Josh",
    "Age": 20.0,
    "Nationality": "UK",
    "Brothers": 2.0
  },
  {
    "Name": "Kim",
    "Age": 22.0,
    "Nationality": "France",
    "Brothers": 1.0
  }
]
```

So two quesitons. How I can insert "Children" field at the begining and how can I get my exact desire output format? Thanks

Comment: `json.dumps({'Children': data})`?

Comment: `json.dumps({'Children': data}, indent=2, sort_keys=True)`.

Comment: I not working. I already tried. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What exactly does "I not working" mean? Incorrect output? Exception thrown?

Comment: Exactly. I ant to have the exact output as shown above. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import xlrd, json

d = {}
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
data=[]

for i in range(1,sh.nrows):
    d={}
    for j in range(sh.ncols):
        d[sh.cell(0,j).value] = sh.cell(i,j).value

    data.append(d)
result={'Children':data}
print(json.dumps(result,indent=2))
```